# Shortcut keys for Extensions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, extension, brave

How to add the shortcut key of extensions in the brave browser?
There is no option of adding a keyboard shortcut key for the extension in the brave browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select extension icon
2. click on manage extension
3. click on setting ---choose extension----find "keyboard shortcuts"
4. click on the keyboard shortcut
5. then you can add shortcut keys for an extension.